# Invoking "php" command from a PHP script causing strange process behavior

Tags: php, process, command-line-interface

I just moved a site from one host to another. The server environment is very similar (LAMP stack) and all the code worked when it got transferred, except one line. I've mutated it a bit for testing and am still getting very odd results:

```
<?php
$out = `php ../test/test.php 123 abc`;
?>
```

When running `php ../test/test.php 123 abc` from the command line in SSH, it works fine, as expected. And when I run: `php testrunner.php` (the file which has only the "$out" line above in it) in SSH, it also works as expected.

But once I load `testrunner.php` from the browser, it just hangs. Using `ps aux | grep php` to monitor the processes, processes seem to spawn up and die down (truncated for brevity):

```
myuser   12790  0.0  0.3 259016 45284  . . . 0:00 php ../test/test.php 123 abc
```

If I modify the "$out" line to be:

```
<?php
$out = `php ../test/test.php 123 abc &`;
?>
```

then I cause that script to run in the background. Surprisingly, a few seconds later when I run `ps aux | grep php` again, it shows the same stuff but with a new PID. I keep running ps aux and keep seeing it with a different PID. This continues for quite some time (several seconds, maybe even a minute).

This is very odd to me, since test.php only has a line to echo some text for testing purposes.

Works fine from the terminal. Hangs and has other weird behavior when invoked from the web. Am I missing something?

(I have evidence by redirecting output to a log file that, when run from the web browser, the PHP script seems to invoke ITSELF instead of the other script, test.php. And when it behaves like this, it doesn't receive any `$argv` parameters... but when I run it from the command line, all is well! Strange?)

UPDATE: Geez... I was just watching the server processes and the PHP ones of test.php started spawning out of control. They multiplied into the hundreds, maybe thousands, of processes: the server was brought down for a minute, SSH and everything. It's back up now, but I can't explain what's going on. There's no loops in the code and both the files involved are super-simple, isolated for testing purposes...

I'm working with my host as they respond to my support ticket, to see if this is environment-related or what... what could cause this to be happening, simply by changing the server environment?

Comment: I'm assuming that you've checked that `shell_exec()` is enabled. What are the permissions on `test.php`? Have you made sure that apache/webserver user has execution privileges on text.php? Privileges might explain why it runs from terminal but not when accessed via the webserver

Comment: shell_exec() is enabled, yes. I've tried leaving permissions regular on test.php (644 I think?) as well as 755, 777, and practically everything in between, including `chmod +x test.php`. I don't have root access to the server, and my host has said, basically, "this should be working" ... hope that clarifies.

Comment: This might sound pedantic, but have you checked the current working directory [`getcwd()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)? Are you sure that the script you're trying to execute is where you think it is and can be accessed? Regardless, it's best to eschew relative paths entirely. Also, it may not be enough that test.php is executable ... the invoking process may need execute permissions on its parent dirs as well. Just throwing out some possibilities ...

Comment: Yeah. I've tried relative and remote paths, verifying that the file exists. (Good to remind, though... you know how many times I've banged my head against the wall before remembering to simply restart httpd??)

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but given that you're on a different environment, is it possible that this is an issue with your PHP executable path? Do you have a shebang in there? (`#!/usr/bin/php`, etc)? I have no idea if this would work, but have you tried `$out = \`/usr/bin/php /abs/path/test/test.php 123 abc\`;` (subing out the correct paths to the php executable and your file)?

Comment: My host has responded, saying that they insist it's my script, but admitting that suphp could be altering the behavior somehow for security reasons... hmm... any other way to start a long-running process without hanging the caller?

Comment: @Matt Do you have PHP configured as an Apache Module, or as CGI? CGI, because it is a shared host I'm guessing.

Comment: Running as Apache Module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My host, A Small Orange, has been helpful, but in the end, all I or they can figure is (from my support ticket):

> ... that SuPHP or some other security-based software we have running as part of our stack is preventing your processes from spawning new processes (because that behavior can be insecure for obvious reasons) ...

In any case, the scripts work fine on my Macbook (very different configuration with nginx)  and on my old host's LAMP stack, which ASO has a similar setup.

Perhaps I will ask about spawning long-running processes without invoking the command line so that the calling script isn't blocked in another question.

Answer (score -3):

Remove the spaces and put underscore

```
$out = `php ../test/test.php_123_abc`;
```

Comment: You should read about the [backtick operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

Comment: @BenD The formatting ate away his backticks. Not that the rest is correct though.

Comment: @Cthulhu, yeah, I know (it's happened to me before), but the answer is basically gibberish, suggesting a misunderstanding of what the backtick does.